# Potentiometer infinite resistance to fixed value

Tags: potentiometer

This maybe a silly question, but my brain is stuck:
I need to add to my audio circuit a potentiometer that can go from infinite ()total interruption to 10k.
imagine a light bulb that can go dark to a fixed dimmed light, and imagine, instead of light, it is audio.

Comment: All potentiometers do this so what's the real issue?

Comment: I assume you mean 'zero' ohms to 10K ohms. Is that correct?

Comment: Draw a circuit diagram

Answer (score 4):

If, for example, this is an audio volume control application an open circuit will leave you with hum pickup problems. Your question needs to be rephrased.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSk2yK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Max volume limited. (b) Minimum volume limited. (c) The wrong way.*

Meanwhile have a look at Figure 1 and see if either (a) or (b) unsticks your brain. Volume controls are almost always configured as potential dividers so we don't do infinite resistance - instead we move the wiper to the grounded end of the potentiometer to give zero output.

The infinite resistance scheme of (c) effectively leaves the input to the next stage disconnected and will act as an antenna to mains hum and electrical noise. You can test this out by unplugging an external speaker's line-level (3.5 mm stereo jack, typically) from your PC, phone or MP3 player's headphone socket and cranking the volume up. Turn down the volume while connecting / disconnecting. (I've been told a sound-engineer dies every time someone connects / disconnects without turning the volume down.)

Edit your original question to clarify and we can update this to suit.

Comment: my short question was: a 100k pot, measure 0 resistance to 100k. what if i wanted a pot that goes the opposite way from infinite signal interrupted to 100K. should i just connect the 3rd pin to ground?

Comment: Please explain the problem you are trying to solve. Put the details in your original question (so everyone who tries to answer can see all the information in one place). Draw a simple schematic using the button on the editor toolbar. "_What if i wanted a pot that goes the opposite way from infinite signal interrupted to 100k?_" No pots have a smooth transition to infinity. Again, explain the problem.